# Is the absolute value function differentiable at x=0

Tags: maxima, wolframalpha, differentiation, absolute-value

Both Wolfram Alpha (`diff abs(x)`) and Maxima (`diff(abs(x),x,1);`) say that the absolute value function is differentiable at x=0, and that the derivative is x/abs(x).

How would you go about excluding the point x=0 from the domain when formulating the query?
Thanks!

P.S. This occurs with Maxima (build_info("5.27.0","2012-05-09 21:24:21","x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu","GNU Common Lisp (GCL)","GCL 2.6.7")).

Comment: If they report that the derivative is x/abs(x) they are in fact reporting that it is not differentiable at 0 since 0/0 is undefined.

Comment: Post it in `Mathematica` for quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In maxima you can use a wrapper function with wider domain:

```
f: abs(x);
df(x):= ''(diff(f, x));
dfun(x):= block([eps: 1e-15], if abs(x)>eps then df(x) else 1);
plot2d(dfun(x), [x, -1, 1], [y, -1.1, 1.1], [ylabel, df(x)]);
```